# Can I use reinterpret_cast to destroy non dynamically allocated objects?

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

I have done a very simple implementation of vector. I admit that I have cheated a lot and the only instance variables are for example `size_t sz` and `T * elem`. The one of many problems (but this one is the only problem I know of which may cause a crash) is the problem with `pop_back()`.

```
template <typename T>
    void vec<T>::pop_back() {
    if (sz == 0)
        return;
    elem[sz-1].~T();
    --sz;
}
```

The vector `elem` is a dynamically allocated array, but the objects in the array may or may not be. The problem I can see here is that this may crash in case I destroy an object in this array. This can happen in case I would destroy elements multiple times. So to say, in case I have used pop_back. This does not seem to happen for my compiler (which seems strange), but I have heard about someone having this problem with this function. I have been trying to do some research on the web and found another [alternative](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/60502). The zero check is not done here (probably laziness), and this example is using reinterpret_cast

```
template<class T>
void Vector<T>::pop_back() {

    // You way want to do a check for empty() before calling the destructor.

    // Call the destructor.
    (reinterpret_cast<T*>(buffer)[_size-1]).~T();

    // It is usual to prefer the pre decrement (and pre increment).
    --_size;
}
```

The question is, **Can I really use reinterpret_cast to be able to destroy non dynamically allocated objects in my vector class?**

**EDIT**

By request I will show my push_back, which I was unsure how to properly write with the short time span I could spend on this. I admit that the main purpose of the class was not efficiency but a good way to handle resources instead of raw dynamic arrays (I can of course use a vector but this is rather a question about a smaller scope than general strategy so I would appreciate if the use-std::vector discussion was left out)

```
template <typename T>
void vec<T>::push_back(const T& obj) {
    T* tmp = new T[sz+1];
    if (sz > 0){
        uninitialized_copy(elem, elem+sz, tmp);
        delete[] elem;
    }
    elem = tmp;
    elem[sz] = T{obj};
    ++sz;
}
```

The main problem was the capacity. I realized the capacity part would require a lot of work and without that I could just create new elements.

Comment: The example you cite uses an "untyped" `char *` buffer in order to avoid unnecessary ctor calls, hence the cast to `T*`. Your array `elem`, by contrast, is already typed, I take it. And directly calling the dtor on an object has nothing to do with dynamic allocation. (Since the object appears to reside in your elem vector you should be in the know about the way it was allocated ;-). )

Comment: I'd be more worried about cases when `T` doesn't have a destructor.  Like a vector of `int` for example.  If `T` is `int` then `var.~int()` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by *"The vector elem is a dynamically allocated array, but the objects in the array may or may not be. "* ? How exactly is your array allocated and how are your objects constructed?

Comment: Show your push_back()

Comment: @CrazyEddie: `var.~int()` may not make sense, but `var.~T()` is fine if T is a template argument instatiated as `int`. It's just a no-op.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is inspired by the stack implementation in the book *Exceptional C++* by Herb Sutter (Item 12):

You can allocate memory for your `vec`, if you initialize your `T * elem` variable with

```
elem = static_cast<T*>(sz == 0 ? nullptr : operator new(sizeof(T)*sz));
```

This will give you memory on which no object has yet been constructed.

*Edit(thanks to Cheers and hth. - Alf): You can also use the allocator instead of the above code by calling `a.allocate(sz)`.*

If you want to add new elements to the vector, you can use `construct` [[1]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/construct).  To call the destructor of an object you can use `destroy` [[2]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/destroy).

If you now keep track on how many elements there are allocated in your vector in a variable `used`, you can deallocate the last by calling `destroy(elem+used);`

`construct` and `destroy` use the placement new and an explicit destructor call inside them.  I would recommend using these functions instead of raw placement news and destructor calls.

Comment: That does indeed seem smart and makes using an allocator as a member to the class seem now like a good idea. Thank you for making a lot of implementations that I have seen make more sense.

Comment: It seems incongruous to use allocator functions like `construct` and `destroy`, but not using the allocator to allocate. What's the idea here?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf We don't want to use a normal `new` because we don't yet want to construct the objects.  Our vector of the size *n* would contain *n* standard constructed objects we want to overwrite later anyways.  So we do the allocation ourselves and call the constructor and destructor explicitly.  `construct` and `destructs` are simply fancy ways to use `new (ptr) T(value)` and `ptr->~T()`.

Comment: @Otomo: All and well, but why are you not **using the allocator to allocate**? It's like, it's called an "allocator" because it, well, allocates. That's it's job, and it's the client code's customization point.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf You are right.  I tried it and it also works with an `std::allocator a;` and `a.allocate(sz);`.  In the class you would have to make sure that you initialize the allocator before you allocate the memory for `elem`.

Comment: A user-supplied allocator object is necessarily already initialized. Here's some [online documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator).

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know that was necessarily the case.